# i want to write validation function in jquery.validate.js for " . "

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

```
slug: function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/.test(value);
        },
```

This is my function for validation of alphabets, numbers and hyphen only but now I want to add .(dot) , so function can accept .(dot), what can I do

Comment: Just add `.` in the character class. `/^[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+$/`

Comment: Why not use the pattern rule and pass the regex - why to write a new rule for that

Comment: I don't know how to write pattern rule in vlidate.js @arun P Johny

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tushar but it gives error like this : " Cannot read property 'call' of undefined "

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g3h94bfo/1/ - can be done like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g3h94bfo/2/ (With additional-methods.js file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to have a custom rule to do this, you can use the pattern rule from the additional-methods.js file like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      somefield: {
        pattern: /^[A-Za-z\d-.]+$/,
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <input name="somefield" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you  @Arun P Johny